# Node app works with express, but getting 404 socket.io when using express-generator

Tags: node.js, express

I've succesfully created socket.io apps using express [example code here](https://github.com/nickklosterman/SocketIOTesting/tree/master/socketIOExpressExample). But when I use express-generator to build the [skeleton](https://github.com/nickklosterman/SocketIOTesting/tree/master/socketIOExpressExampleFromGeneratedExpress), I've been unsuccessful. I'm getting the dreaded

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js HTTP 404 error. 
ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

I'm at a loss to determine how to get it all working. I tried to take the working code and migrate that code into the express-generated code.

If I remember correctly, I simply used the express-generator to build the skeleton.  I then added in the code from [here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io#in-conjunction-with-expres) and threw that in my `app.js` and added in the io.sockets.on(...) code as well. I had to adapt the index.html code for the index.jade file. I really think that is it. Alas, I'm stumped as to what I'm doing wrong transferring the code from a basic express app to that of the skeleton created by the express generator. I'm not an express master by any means but figured that if basic express worked, that using the express generated skeleton it would all work as well. It appears that I'm missing something or there are special considerations to take into account.

node v0.10.28

socket.io v1.0.2

express v4.2.0

Comment: Can you please post your final code that gives the error?

Comment: The final code is found on github at the link highlighted by `skeleton` --> https://github.com/nickklosterman/SocketIOTesting/tree/master/socketIOExpressExampleFromGeneratedExpress. When I run the app and open the page I get `"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://10.20.99.169:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1402431458240"
`

Comment: What version of socket.io are you using on the server? Make sure client and server match

Comment: Changing `script(src='/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js')` to `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")` in my `layout.jade` file fixed the problem. Thanks for the hint Avery! If you want the rep points post the solution and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
script(src='/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js')
```

do

```
script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
```

This is because socket.io automatically fufills requests for it's client file through express. Manually linking to it will cause problems, especially if the static file is a different version than the installed module.